# Directory size error

Tags: powershell, directory

I have a script to check the size of a folder and all of its sub-folders and it does what I need but it throws errors if the folder has size 0.  I would like to add some logic in but I cant seem to find a good way to do it, thanks in advance for the help.

The script is:

```
$startFolder = "C:\"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

Comment: What error does it throw? On what line? Add logic to do what?

Comment: You are missing a { on the Where-Object block that you posted too.

Comment: It was a PowerShell tip of the week lol... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx

Comment: The error is: Measure-Object : Property "length" cannot be found in any object(s) input.
At C:\directorysize.ps1:9 char:70
+         $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object <<<<  -
property length -sum)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumen 
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerSh 
   ell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand

from what I can tell its the measure-object -property length, it has no length so it errors.

Yes it is the tip, it is exactly what I needed...without the error

Comment: hmmm...I can't get it to error for me. Have you tried -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue on the Measure-Object cmdlet?

Comment: I spoke too soon. I could get it to error and SilentlyContinue worked

Comment: I had not tried that.  It works perfectly now, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me without errors:

```
$startFolder = "C:\"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

Comment: This needs an opening { in the line: $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got this. The error happens when one folder has no file, even if it has non-empty folders. The solution posted by EBGreen is incomplete, because it takes only sub-files into consideration.

The correct script is:

```
$folder = $args[0]
[console]::WriteLine($folder)
$startFolder = $folder

#here we need the size of all subfiles and subfolders. Notice the -Recurse
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
"------"

#here we take only the first level subfolders. Notice the Where-Object clause and NO -Recurse
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $i.FullName
        #here we need again the size of all subfiles and subfolders, notice the -Recurse
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        "                                   -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

Now there's no error and the values are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the output of `Get-ChildItem` is $null for empty folders. Measure-Object is expecting an input object with a property of length. So you can just omit that processing for folders are empty like this:

```
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    if ($i.GetFileSystemInfos().Count) {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
}
```